# explicit/implicit type conversion c++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

I have a line of code

```
double i = 1 + (long)1.5* 5.0f
```

My question is what is the conversion order and the result? Been searching for examples like this, but to no avail. Any good guides out there that may help me understand it?

Comment: If you are not sure, put brackets into your code. ((long)(1.5 * 5.0f))

Comment: Are you talking about precedence table?

Comment: @MartinPerry - if you are not sure, do some research. Blindly adding parentheses usually makes an unreadable mess. Or, in this case, use a new style cast: `static_cast<long>(1.5*5.0f)` seems like a good candidate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is what is the conversion order and the result?

The cast is applied to `1.5`, giving a `long` with value `1`.

That's converted to `float` for multiplication with `5.0f`, giving a `float` with value `5.0f`.

`1` is converted to `float` for addition with that value, giving a `float` with value `6.0f`.

Finally, that's promoted to `double` (retaining the value `6.0`) to assign to `i`.

This assumes a non-crazy floating point format that can represent small integers exactly; otherwise, there may be rounding errors.

If you wanted to cast the result of the multiplication, then use parentheses to control the operator precedence:

```
double i = 1 + (long)(1.5* 5.0f);  // = 8.0
```

or use a C++-style cast, which forces the use of parentheses:

```
double i = 1 + static_cast<long>(1.5* 5.0f)
```

> Any good guides out there that may help me understand it?

Here's one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. Note that the type cast has a higher precedence than multiplication, which is in turn higher than addition (3 vs. 5 vs. 6).

Comment: *"1 is promoted to float"*. Is the term "promoted" correct here? I think it should be "converted".

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes, you're right. I can never remember exactly which is which.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Is is really important?  (For what it's worth: promotions occur even if the two operands have the same type.  Every thing else is conversion.  Also, I think that the only time a floating point promotion takes place is as a function argument matching `...`)

Comment: @JamesKanze: No, it's not important, but there are enough pedants around here that I prefer to get things right.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It is not important here. But I'm working hard to get used to the terms that the spec uses, so that when I look at the spec/proposals/drafts, it may appear comprehensible to me. And in my first comment, I was merely looking for confirmation that I understand the thing correctly. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the cast operator has higher precedence than multiplication, but follow the advice to use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

[This precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) should tell you everything you need to know.

1. Casting: `1.5` is cast to a `long`
2. Multiplication: `1.5 * 5.0f`, which casts this product as a `float`
3. Addition: `1 + ( ((long) 1.5) * 5.0f)`
4. Assignment: `i = 1 + ((long) 1.5 * 5.0f)`

Comment: The cast to long means that the multiplication is `1L * 5.0F`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure what the precedence of the casting operator is then rewrite the expression (in your head)

```
(long)1.5 * 5.0
```

to

```
5.0 * (long)1.5
```

Here its pretty obvious what has precedence and its the same with the first version